# How to make UL surround its content and nothing more?

Tags: html, css

I saw really nice progress "bar" (here: http://www.alessioatzeni.com/wp-content/tutorials/html-css/CSS3-Loading-Animation/index.html first from the top). The difference in my case is I enter `ul` element manually, but all `li`'s will be added dynamically.

The key issue here is all `li` elements are set to float to left, so they make nice line of dots. I would like to have such `ul` that surrounds its content and occupy as much space as its children in total -- then I could nicely center `ul`.

To my surprise I cannot do this. In block mode `ul` has big margin on left (I don't know where it comes from) and it occupies entire width of its parent. When I set display to inline the `ul` is **outside** its children -- but the width is correct.

I am struggling with this for some time, any tip would be great (once again: I would like to have dots in single line, in such way, that I could center entire `ul`; I would like to avoid computing `ul` width manually, because it is easy to miscalculate some margin and get strange results in various browsers).

Test code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
<style>
html, body { 
    height: 100% 
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
}

li {
    float: left;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 50px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    border-left: 1px solid #111;
    border-top: 1px solid #111;
    border-right: 1px solid #333;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
    background: #000;
}

li:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}

</style>    
</head>
<body>


<div style="border-style:solid"><ul style="display:inline">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
</div>    


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/6gGj5/5/?

Comment: @Danko, WOW! Thank you, now I have to look **why** it works. Please post your comment as reply so I could accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the `UL` centered and dynamic `width` you can use `display:inline-block` and `text-align:center` on his parent.

This is the demo **http://jsfiddle.net/6gGj5/7/**

- First I reset margin and padding for all elements to prevent the default values for items like `ul`:

  ```
  * {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
  }
  ```
- Second add:

  ```
  div {
   text-align:center;
  }
  ul {
   display:inline-block;
   text-align:center;
  }
  li {
   display:inline-block; /*instead of float*/
  }
  ```

<sub>Also add inline-block to li instead of float to avoid the need of clear elements</sub>

Comment: Thank you again for clear explanation. You've been very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Trying to minimize changes to example I came up with this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
<style>
html, body { 
    height: 100% 
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
    width:44px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    background-color:red;
}

li {
    float: left;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 50px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    border-left: 1px solid #111;
    border-top: 1px solid #111;
    border-right: 1px solid #333;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
    background: #000;
}

li:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}

</style>    
</head>
<body>


<div style="border-style:solid; clear:both;">
<ul>
    <li>&nbsp;</li>
    <li>&nbsp;</li>
</ul>
</div>    


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, it works nicely, but you hardcoded `width`. Since `il` will be added dynamically it means I would have to computer it on my own -- it is to easy to conflict with browser. So I am looking for another approach. +1 for killing the margin :-)

Comment: yeah trying to avoid changing things I hard coded stuff. I think Danko  got it right.